Seeking the exact shloka in the Bhagavata purana regarding responding to insults against god
There is a shloka I think in bhagvata-puran which says that if someone is insulting god, stop him if you have power, if don't have power to stop him, just go away, never hear words against god i.e. "iswar ninda/shiv-ninda ke sakshi mat bano".
Can someone pls tell me that exact shloka and its origin scripture?

The Omniscient All-knowing Lord does not need our protection, we need His. Perhaps insulting God is that person's way of praying. Who knows? Who are we to judge? Does the yapping of dogs upset an elephant? - Pray, Lord why does this upset my mindfulness of Thee? Please allow nothing to divert my remembrance of Thee.
